# How to download a file using Express and Node.js in Response to a Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, download, stream

So I have a a bunch of files that I'd like users to be able to download by submitting a form (sending a get request I suppose). Can someone tell me how to change my views, routes and app.js files to be able to do this? Should the routing be handled in the index.js file (where the users can download the files)? Or should I make a brand new route using the app.js file?

Edit: I'm using multer to upload the files.

My somewhat scattered code at this point:

in the app.js we have this:

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res, next){
  var file = req.params.file
    , path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file;

  res.download("upload/a.tiff");
});
```

in the index.jade we have this:

```
h2 Download
form(action="/download", method="get")
  input(type="submit", name="downLoad")
```

There is nothing relevant in the index.js file but at one point I had the function in the app.js that I've listed in the index.js file. That did not seem to work.

Right now I have just trying to be able to download the one a.tiff file.

This is the error:

```
404

Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/app.js:39:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at /Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603:15
    at next (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:14)
    at Function.proto.handle (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:3)
    at router (/Users/brennan/personal/dev/shareBetweenComputers/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:35:12)
```

do I need to write a route for downloading?

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/download?downLoad=Submit
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Comment: Need some code here. What does your existing routes/views look like

Comment: @laggingreflex Is there anything else I should include? The rest is pretty much just outta the box express.

Comment: *looks like* it should work. Is your `app.get('/download'..` function getting called? What does the [browser network console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview) show about requests being sent/received when you submit the form

Comment: @laggingreflex its not being called. I get a 404 as what received and the request is up there as well.

Comment: What happens when you goto (from browser) `http://localhost:3000/download`? If your route isn't getting called it must be getting skipped for some reason. Could you post the surrounding code in your app.js?